# How to make Developer Tools in MS Edge to default to Console tab instead of Sources?

Tags: microsoft-edge, ie11-developer-tools

Whenever I open the Developer Tools or if the web page is refreshed, Tools will switch to the Sources tab.

When I'm debugging code, I want it to stay on the Console tab.   Is there a way to do this?  Or even keep Console on-top.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've searched about this issue and I found that there is a setting in the default configuration of the developer tools to automatically foucus the Resource tab when a breakpoint is triggered, this should be the cause of the problem.

But you can disable this option by following these steps:

1. In Edge, open `devtools` in any way.
2. Focus in devtools and press key `F1` to open settings panel.
3. In `Preferences` tab, scroll down and find the option `Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint`.
4. Uncheck this option and restart open devtools.

**Something like this below**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This did the trick.